# Append HTML File Using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to add an HTML file to my laravel view, but I can't.

My back code:

```
$fls = array();
foreach ($docItems as $key => $value) {
  $fl = array("flName" => $value["tab_name"], "flContent" => readfile("documents/". $referenceId . 
    "/" . $value["tab_name"] . ".html"));
  array_push($fls, $fl);
}
$data['itemsContent'] = $fls;

return view('pages.doc', $data);
```

My laravel blade view code:

```
@foreach ($itemsContent as $k => $v)
    <div>{{ $v["flContent"] }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Do you guys know why it is not working? I mean, it is adding my html code, but at the beginning of the page, and this is not what I want. Ahh and I am using Laravel 7 and PHP 7.

Comment: If you wish to render the html, then try `{!!  !!}`. `{{ }}` espaces the html so it won't render. but beware of user supplied content

Comment: yeah, it solved my problem.. thank you so much! =D.. but I have to say that I need to convert my html file as a text on code-behind, using the html file directly, the {!! !!} won't solve